# How would I apply throwing a ball against an obstacle physics in unity2d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So basically what I want is that imagine I shoot a ball at a box i want it to come back at me if shot it straight and vice versa.
Below is the image of what I mean [image: Image of what i want]

In case above image isnt working for you https://ibb.co/MVbdmGK

Comment: I don’t quite understand what you want. By the picture, you want it to bounce off and immediately go towards another box. Is that what you want?

Comment: Are you trying to use the Unity physics system or are you wanting to use your own solution?

Comment: @ken yes  I want simple physics like when I hit a ball at a wall it bounces back, As in this situation if i hit ball on certain side of the box it should go as physics would.

Comment: Look for unity physics and rigidbody tutorial

Comment: @MalikNouman When you say "it bounces back", do you mean just like normal physics? Are you talking about real-world physics? If you are, like @MarkSouls says in his comment, you should check out rigidbodies and the unity physics. Here is a [link about rigidbodies](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html), and here is a link about [`AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) which you could use to throw the object.

Comment: Thank you guys I know about most stuff I wasnt adding physicsMaterial so it wasnt working.